# Installed ISAPI and CGI, but both are disabled in IIS

Tags: iis, cgi, isapi

Installed ISAPI and CGI with the IIS role, but they are disabled as seen in the attached image.[screenshot of Roles and IIS windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NLW7.jpg)
Scratching my head a bit here.

Comment: They are disabled because they are pre-2000 stuffs which in general you never should use. Today if you enable ISAPI and CGI support, you are most likely to configure things like FastCGI, where you will create new handler mappings instead of enabling those disabled ones, like in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-a-php-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-php#to-download-and-install-php-and-wincache

Comment: Its required for a third part server application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just had to enable Execute in the Feature Settings, no longer disabled.